# RevolutionPlot3D: but NOT revolving about the z axis

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to demonstrate generating a solid of revolution by revolving a planar region about, say, a horizontal axis. However, `RevolutionPlot3D` doesn't seem to have an option for revolving a curve about something other than the $z$ axis. I'm curious how you all would handle this.

Here's a simple example:

```
theta0 = Pi;
Manipulate[
  GraphicsRow[{
    Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, Filling -> Axis],
    Rotate[RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, theta0 - .001, T},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 1}], -Pi/2]
  }],
{T, theta0, theta0 + 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

My questions:

1. Is there a "better" way to showcase revolving about a horizontal axis of revolution than what I've done with `Rotate`?
2. Is it possible to generate the higher quality, finished surface of revolution while the slider bar is moving instead of only when the slider is released?
3. How do I prevent the vertical tick labels on the far left edge as well as the graphic on the far right edge from being clipped? (I tried `Spacings` and `ImagePadding`.)
4. How do I vertically align the horizontal axis of revolution of the right graphic with the horizontal axis of the left graphic?

**Edit:** I had a follow up question but I will spin that off as a separate question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answers:

1. `RevolutionAxis`, set to either `"X"` or `{1,0,0}`.  (This also required adjustments to the `PlotRange` and `ViewPoint` options.)
2. `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`
3. I switched from `GraphicsRow` to `Row`, which I like much better.  (I then also set `ImageSize -> Small` to make the plots a bit bigger than they'd naturally be in `Row`.)
4. I was able to align the plots pretty well by setting `BaselinePosition` for each of the plots.

I also turned off the `Mesh` since I felt it was distracting, especially at the beginning of the sequence.

```
theta0 = Pi;
Manipulate[Row[{
   Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, 
       Filling -> Axis, BaselinePosition -> Axis, ImageSize -> Small], 
   RevolutionPlot3D[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {t, theta0 - .001, T}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
       Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, -2, 0}, 
       Mesh -> None, RevolutionAxis -> "X", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
       BaselinePosition -> Center, ImageSize -> Small]
   }], {T, theta0, theta0 + 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed the `RevolutionAxis` option. As for #3, is there an explicit parameter which controls the amount of white space surrounding the outside edge of the graphics (but inside the `Manipulate` frame)?

Comment: `ImagePadding` should do that.

Answer (score 10):

If you really would like to show volume, then an alternative simple approach is to use `RegionPlot3D`, which is easy to specify in cylindrical coordinates and then come back to Cartesian. We need some clever trick though to improve `Arg` function's limited domain, because this Demo stops at Pi/2:

```
Manipulate[

 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u, 0, u^2}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],

  RegionPlot3D[Arg[z + I y] < T && 0 < Sqrt[y^2 + z^2] < x^2 && 0 < x < 10, {x, 0,
     1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], PlotPoints -> 25]

  , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> .3]

 , {{T, 0, "rotation angle"}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Other fancy things you could do are below. Which axes to rotate about is relative. You can do many things to beautify your plot. Is it something like that you need? Note you can rotate the plot freely - so axis point in directions you want. Take a look at [**some Demonstrations and their code here**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=volume%20calculus) to learn other techniques.

```
Manipulate[

 Show[

  ParametricPlot3D[{u^2, 0, u}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],

  RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Specularity[White, 10]}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
   MeshShading -> ms, PlotPoints -> 30]

  , Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.1, 2.6, 1.73}, ViewVertical -> {1.4, 0.3, 0.2}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> .4, ImageSize -> 600, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]

 , {{ms, None, 
   "shades"}, {None -> "NO", {{Red, Yellow}, {Pink, Orange}} -> "YES"}}
 , {{T, 2 Pi}, .001, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe "accomplish" would have been a better word than "showcase" in Question #1. I don't necessarily want anything fancy, like coloring options, etc. I just want to rotate about a horizontal axis with code that is simple for students.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness: one can always fall back on using the definition of a surface of revolution if you are not satisfied with how *Mathematica* is rotating your curve. (I assume that your starting curves are embedded in the $x$-$z$ coordinate plane.) Either of

```
With[{axis = {1, 0, 0}},
     ParametricPlot3D[RotationMatrix[θ, axis].{x, 0, x^2} // Evaluate,
                      {x, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                      ViewPoint -> {3, -2, 1}]]
```

or

```
With[{axis = {1, 0, 0}},
     ParametricPlot3D[RotationTransform[θ, axis][{x, 0, x^2}] // Evaluate,
                      {x, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                      ViewPoint -> {3, -2, 1}]]
```

work nicely:

[image: some surface of revolution]

If you need to rotate with respect to some axis not passing through the origin, the code I gave is easily modified:

```
With[{origin = {3, 1, 0}, axis = {1, 0, 1}},
     ParametricPlot3D[RotationTransform[θ, axis, origin][{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}] // Evaluate,
                      {t, π, 2 π}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                      ViewPoint -> {3, -2, 1}]]
```

[image: some torus]

Note that in this example, I rotated a general parametric curve as opposed to a function.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks.