# RevolutionPlot3D: axis of revolution that doesn't pass through the origin

Tags: plotting

This is a follow up question to [RevolutionPlot3D: but NOT revolving about the z axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/revolutionplot3d-but-not-revolving-about-the-z-axis) so please check that for the context.

It seems that `RevolutionAxis` requires the axis of revolution to pass thru the origin. 
Suppose I want to use an axis of revolution that does not pass through the origin, e.g., the line $y=-1$ in the example above. What is a good way to accomplish this?

I do realize that `RegionPlot3D` may be appropriate here, but even with seemingly simple examples such as the one above, it can struggle:

```
Show[
  RegionPlot3D[1 <= Sqrt[(y + 1)^2 + z^2] <= 1 + x^2, {x, 0, 1}, 
    {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    Mesh -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    ViewPoint -> {0.87, 0.44, 1.76}, ViewVertical -> {0.32, 0.67, 0.67}],
  Graphics3D[{Thickness[.01], Black, Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {1.15, -1, 0}}]}]
]
```

[image]

Bumping `PlotPoints` up to 200, 300, 400 doesn't alleviate the problem and gets really slow.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to give yet another example of how Simon Woods's [`contourRegionPlot3D`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/9490) can produce flawless results:

```
Show[
 contourRegionPlot3D[
  1 <= Sqrt[(y + 1)^2 + z^2] <= 1 + x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -3, 
   3}, {z, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[.01], Black, 
   Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {1.15, -1, 0}}]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Generate the plot and then apply a translation:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], t, Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}, 
                 PlotRange -> All] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[p_List, rest__] :> GraphicsComplex[TranslationTransform[{5, 5, 0}][p], rest]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand this approach. How would I use it to generate the solid of revolution in the question? Thanks.