# How to Plot the Surface Generated by a Curve Revolved about a Line which doesn't go through the Origin

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the 3D surface generated by revolving the 2D curve f(x)=x^2 about the axis y=1.  It seems `RevolutionPlot3D[]` only allows you to choose an axis that passes through the origin with the `RevolutionAxis` option with a single vector.  The code below generates the graph but revolved around the x-axis (y=0).

```
RevolutionPlot3D[t^2, {t, 0, 20}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> 10]
```

If I can't modify `RevolutionPlot[]` to suit my need, how you would suggest I go about achieving this functionality?

Comment: See J.M.'s answer in a linked topic. Another one related: [8512](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8512/5478) p.s. as always, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to mind is to use `Translate` (or `GeometricTransformation` more generally). ...plus a few styling tips.

```
revplt = RevolutionPlot3D[t^2, {t, 0, 20}, {θ, 0, Pi}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> "X", MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> 100, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.6], PlotPoints -> 60];

Graphics3D[{
  Translate[revplt[[1]], {0, 1, 0}],
  {Red, Thick, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}]}
  }, PlotRange -> 3, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, Blue] & /@ {"X", "Y", "Z"}), 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]