# How to revolve a surface about a line other than the $x,y,z$ axes?

Tags: plotting

I just started working with *Mathematica* 8 and I'm having trouble revolving a function the way I want.

I have to revolve the function $x^2/4 +2$ and $y= 0$ around $y=6$ to form an ashtray, but I can't find how to do it.

EDIT:
So far I've got :

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{f[x] - 6}, {-6}}, {x, 0, 6}, RevolutionAxis -> x]
```

And for clarification, this is the complete surface I'm revolving (Or trying to)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/irpaw37nayox414/Capture.PNG

Now I just need to revolve the explicit functions "x=0" from 0 to 2 and "x=5" 0 t0 6

Comment: You say you'd like to rotate about $y=6$ but that's not an axis; could you explain?

Comment: Why don't you just rotate the graph of $y=x^2/4 + 2 - 6$ around the y-axis? You will get the same shape.  However, I don't see an "ashtray" there: perhaps you really want to rotate this graph around the y-axis?

Comment: So the only way to do it is modifying the function?

Either way, it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8461/121

Answer (score 7):

You'll need some of these as well:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red,
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0.05, 0.05, 0.05}}, 1/2],
  Gray,
  Cylinder[{{0.05, 0.05, 0.05}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2}}, 1/2],
  White,
  Cylinder[{{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {3, 3, 3}}, 1/2],
  Orange,
  Cylinder[{{3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}, 1/2],
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: drawing these is a bit of a fag]

Comment: I'm working on it :P. Now I just need to figure out how to revolve implicit functions.

Comment: +1 for using graphics glitches to your advantage.

Comment: I'm glad to see you're not a smoker. (They would know that the ash is at the tip and the burning part lies between the ash and the unburned part). :-)

Comment: Took me a while to figure out where the texture came from.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are expecting.

```
ClearAll@f;
f[x_] := x;
RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0, 4}, RevolutionAxis -> {6, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

does revolve it around an axis which, as specified, is pointing along the $x$ axis.

Comment: Isn't your figure revolving around the x-axis?

Comment: @DavidCarraher oh yes, that was why I added the labels... thanks for pointing the typo out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
RevolutionPlot3D[(x^2/4 + 2) - 6, {x, -4, 4}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```