# RevolutionPlot3D: revolving around a line NOT an axis

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to revolve a function around a line instead of an axis?

For instance I would like to revolve the quadratic function:

```
f[x_]:=-0.45(x-1.5)^2
```

Around the `x=3, z=0` line.

Comment: [Strongly related?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/revolutionplot3d-but-not-revolving-about-the-z-axis)

Comment: What do you want to revolve? I may be able to translate all by `{-3, 0, 0}` and then use `RevolutionAxis->`

Comment: I want to revolve a quadratic function: -0.45(x - 1.5)^2

Comment: Yes, sorry x=3 z=0

Answer (score 3):

General approach is covered by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8516/5478) form the Q&A which link is provided by Öskå.

As I've said in comments, you may translate your function so the `x = 3, z = 0` line will be an y-axis.

```
f[x_] := (-0.45 (x - 1.5)^2)

Plot[{f[x], f[x + 3]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Line[{{3, -25}, {3, 5}}], Red, Line[{{0, -25}, {0, 5}}]}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads@.05]
```

[image]

Then revolve it around y-axis:

```
plot = RevolutionPlot3D[{x, f[x + 3], 0}, {x, -5, 5},
                      RevolutionAxis -> {0, 1, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
                      ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> 15, BaseStyle -> Orange,
                      AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
                     ]
```

[image]

and translate it back:

```
Translate[#, {3, 0, 0}] & @@ plot //Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 15,
                                           AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},  ImageSize -> 500,
                                           AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Add a cool `MeshShading` and you got a Smurf house

Comment: @MichaelH General approach is covered by [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8516/5478) form this Q&A which link is provided by Oska