# Revolve A Function Around the Y axis?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I am seeking to revolve the are between the functions function $d(x) = Exp(x)$ and $e(x) = 4 - x^2$ around the line $x = 2$. I am using `RevolutionPlot3D`, so I thought it best to use the Y axis instead. Here is the modified code:

```
d[x_] := E^(x + 2)
e[x_] := 4 - (x + 2)^2

RevolutionPlot3D[{{d[x]}, {e[x]}}, {x, -1.96464 - 2, 1.05801 - 2}, 
                RevolutionAxis -> "Y"]
```

However, I find that the code does not produce the revolution that I am seeking. Is there a syntax error or an error in my methodology? Any push in the right direction would be quite helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Arbitrary axis approach by J. M.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8516/5478) and [strongly related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30435/5478) almost the same case

Comment: The region you want to rotate is ambiguous! Is the region you want rotated the "quasi-triangular" region bounded by the line $x = 1$ on its left, the curve $y = 4 - x^2$ above, and the curve $y = exp(x)$ below?

Comment: Have you tried `RevolutionAxis -> "Z"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are seeking ?

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, d[x], 0}, {x, e[x], 0}}, 
 {x, -1.96464 - 2,  1.05801 - 2}, RevolutionAxis -> "Y"]
```

[image]