# How would I rotate a table of Cuboids around the y axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Currently I can print out this using Graphics3d:
[image: Graph]
Here's the code:

```
a = (-5 \[Pi])/2;
b = (5 \[Pi])/2;
dx = (b - a)/50;
f[x_] := 2 Cos[x];
startpos[1, k_] := a + (k - 1) dx;
startpos[2, k_] := a + k*dx;
startpos[3, k_] := a + (2 k - 1)/2 dx;

model = Graphics3D[{Table[
Cuboid[{{a + (l - 1) dx, 0, 0}, {a + l*dx, +.01, 
   f[startpos[3, l]] + .01}}], {l, 1, 50, 1}]}];

Show[model]
```

I want to rotate it around the y-axis. I already tried using RevolutionPlot3d, but I'm not sure how to set it up exactly.
Here's my failed attempt:

```
model = RevolutionPlot3D[{Table[
 Cuboid[{{a + (l - 1) dx, 0, 0}, {a + l*dx, +.01, 
    f[startpos[3, l]] + .01}}], {l, 1, 50, 1}]}, {x, a, b}, 
RevolutionAxis -> "Y", AspectRatio -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.1]] ;
Show[model]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8461/131

Comment: Do you want a surface of revolution?  Or do you simply want to enable rotation of the cuboids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch approach to something like:

```
Show[
     RevolutionPlot3D[2 Cos[Floor[x, (Pi/10)]], {x, 0, 9 Pi/2 + .2}, 
                      Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, MeshStyle -> Thick],
     RevolutionPlot3D[0, {x, 0, 9 Pi/2}, Exclusions -> None, 
                                         PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> Thick]
     ,
     ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first version acutely reminded me of a [Guglhupf](https://google.de/search?q=guglhupf&oq=guglh&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j5j0.2978j0j4&client=chrome-mobile&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espvd=1&ie=UTF-8#q=guglhupf&tbm=isch)  (yum)! Please roll back to the delicious seasonal function.

Comment: @YvesKlett Wow, that name sounds like a joke :) But yum indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, no need to use `Show`, simply remove the `;` from the end of your `Graphics3D` expressions.

Secondly, try evaluating:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[Cuboid[{{a + (l - 1) dx, 0, 0}, {a + l*dx, +.01, 
     f[startpos[3, l]] + .01}}], {l, 1, 50, 1}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, Ticks -> None, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12]]
```

[image: Orientation plot]

Are you sure you want to rotate it about the *y*-axis?  Isn't it going to be a mess?

I suspect you mean the *x*-axis, in which case basically you want to replace `Cuboid[{{x0,0,0},{x1,y1,z1}}] -> Cylinder[{{x0,0,0},{x1,0,0}},Abs[z1]]`.  (And forget about `RevolutionPlot3D` which creates surfaces of revolution rather than revolving graphics primitives.)

```
model = Graphics3D[
  Table[Cylinder[{{a + (l - 1) dx, 0, 0}, {a + l*dx, 0, 0}}, 
    Abs[f[startpos[3, l]]]], {l, 1, 50}]]
```

[image: Rotated plot]

Comment: OP said y but I think he meant `z`. But not x. Maybe you are right, I don't know... :)

Comment: @Kuba You're bound to be correct, that's the more difficult axis!